# How come there is no hole in the ground when Kylo Ren fired upon the self-projection of Luke Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren

Why wasn't a giant hole created when Kylo Ren fired upon the vision of Luke Skywalker?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, there is a hole behind Luke, but barely visible, and maybe a bit too small given the massive rain of fire that poured upon him. And the hole's immediate surroundings are undisturbed, which can't be right given the cloud of debris created as the walkers fire.

The first shot:

[image: First shot]

Increase firepower:

[image: More fire]

I said increase firepower!

[image: Keep firing aholes!]

Just a tiny scar on the ground?

[image: Hole?]

Plus, there's a bit of a continuity error anyway, because the massive damage from the siege cannon is also absent during the fight between Kylo and Luke. I guess the SFX team missed something on that scene, which would also explain why we don't have a big hole behind Luke.

Comment: Exactly. Well done. Thank you. (And indeed the hole would be behind him ... so why isn't that entire wall of rock also falling on his projected head?)

Comment: This would be better with a [freehand red circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/398063) - kidding, nice catch :p

Comment: @RandyZeitman That's no rockwall but the door to the old rebel base. The canon punched a tiny hole in it, compared to it's size. It's not going to fall down any time soon. Since you like the answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the right, thank you.

Comment: From the looks of it, the red area immediately surrounding him has been fused into glass, which would explain the general lack of holes.

Comment: The sequence shows quite a bit of material being sent flying up when the blaster shots hit the ground around Luke. I don't think that even fused material can withstand so many direct impacts focused on such a small area.

Comment: I have no proof of this of course, but could it be possible that Luke absorbed or redirected the blast energy?? It's not like he couldn't physically interact, which he did in previous scenes where he passed on Han's dice.

Comment: Interesting theory, though it would be more logical and probably less draining for him to simply revert to ghost form once he'd given the fake dices to Leia. (Remember that the dices vanish when Kylo hold them.) And it shows that he's not physical at the start of the fight with Kylo as he doesn't leave footsteps in the snow contrary to Kylo.

Comment: @Sava: "The canon punched a tiny hole in it" – This is the opposite of what normally happens in Star Wars, giant holes punched into canon.